# Recyclerview Opens Dialog Multiple Times (item amount)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm populating data into a recyclerview which is in a Dialog.
When I click it opens the dialog multiple time, the amount of the items.

First I thought I've put the dialog in a for loop, but I didn't.

```
    final List<getterInterests> listInterests = new ArrayList<>();

pullData data1 = new pullData(Profil.this);
                            data1.getData("", "8", new VolleyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onUserExists(String[] result) {
        for(String res : result){
            getterInterests getterInterests = new getterInterests(res);
            listInterests.add(getterInterests);
        }


        Dialog dialogInterests = new Dialog(Profil.this);
        dialogInterests.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_interests);
        InterestsAdapter interestsAdapter = new InterestsAdapter(Profil.this,listInterests);
        final RecyclerView recyclerViewInterests = dialogInterests.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewInterests);
        recyclerViewInterests.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(Profil.this,3));
        recyclerViewInterests.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerViewInterests.setAdapter(interestsAdapter);

        dialogInterests.show();


    }

    @Override
    public void OnSuccess() {

    }

    @Override
    public void OnError(String ErrorMessage) {
        Toast.makeText(Profil.this, ErrorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think the problem is not here. add the code for your dialog.you can but a Log inside `onUserExist()` you will see it is called once. so the problem is in your dialog. add it's code

Comment: You're right. onUserExist() is the problem.